# Parameters for a Levy distribution in R

Tags: distributions, parameterization

Can someone help me figure out how I can get parameter estimates for a levy distribution using R? Unlike the normal distribution and Student T distribution which has functions `nFit(x)` and `stdFit(x)` respectively, the Levy distribution doesn't seem to have the same ability. I am trying to fit my data set to the levy distribution so I need a function in R that will give me good estimates for the delta and gamma parameters.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any `nFit` nor `stdFit` functions in the distribution of R. Are you talking about some package? Please also define what the $\delta$ and $\gamma$ parameters are in your parameterization. For example, wikipedia gives $\mu$ and $c$ instead - how do they correspond?

Failing that, please at least give the cdf or the density for your form so we can see how it's parameterized.

You can probably use `fitdistr` from `MASS` to fit it, you just need to supply the density (which is simple) and some start values.

Comment: Yes, nFit is from the package fBasics and stdFit is from the package fGarch. So, I was able to use those two packages to calculate the parameters(mu and sigma) for a normal distribution and (mu, sd, and nu) for a symmetric student T distribution. Now I am looking to calculate the following parameters for a Levy distribution : delta and gamma.Delta is the location parameter which is μ in wikipedia. gamma is c in wikipedia which I believe is the scale parameter. Can you help?

Comment: I am still learning a lot about the levy distribution however, according to R, the formula is the following: f(y;gamma,delta) = sqrt(gamma / (2 pi)) exp( -gamma / (2(y - delta))) / (y - δ)^{3/2}. I got this from typing in "?levy" in R which also showed me the following: levy(delta = NULL, link.gamma = "loge", idelta = NULL, igamma = NULL)... but I don't know how to use that to get the parameters. It is under the package VGAM.

Comment: I tried to take your advice and did the following: test.fit<-function(x,delta,gamma) dt(sqrt(gamma / (2*pi)) * exp( -gamma / (2*(x - delta))) / (x - delta)^{3/2})
fitdistr(x,test.fit,list(delta=0,gamma=1,)).. however, now I am stuck. I keep getting error messages at "fitdistr()". Assuming there is no built in function for the Levy distribution, any ideas how to proceed? Thanks

Comment: any ideas on how I can move forward with this?